# Can't print colors after upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, printing

Since I upgraded from 12.04 to 14.04 I can't print in color anymore.

I have checked all the settings I could think of and tried printing from different applications and printers. Everything is printed in B&W.

How can I go about troubleshooting this problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does anybody else have this problem or is it just a problem with my ubuntu installation? I think I will have to reinstall the 12.04 version.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Configure your printer]

Without Internet Connection, driver download will be failed. But this is the trick to let the system uses Gutenprint drive

[image: Select your printer]

[image: Without Internet Connection, driver download will be failed. But this is the trick to let the system uses Gutenprint driver]

[image: select CMYK]

Answer (score 1):

I could not get my Samsung CLP-680ND to print color from Ubuntu 14.04. What ever I did with all the samsung drivers only resulted in monochrome printing.

However I found I could print in color using:
`HP-Color_LaserJet_CM3530_MFP-PDF.ppd`

I copied this to etc/cups/ppd and made permissions:

- read/write (owner)
- read (group)
- read (others)

And when creating the printer entry:
[choose driver dialogue: select option "provide ppd file"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fE4wj.png)